# RXJS: How to throttle Observable from Promise

Tags: rxjs

I am using RxJS 5.5.10.

I try to throttle an observable to fire every 5 seconds.

This Observable is based on a Promise.

```
  Rx.Observable.fromPromise(mongo.AllWishes)
    .flatMap(array => Rx.Observable.from(array))
    .pluck('url')
    .filter(s => s !== undefined)
    .subscribe(m => console.log(m))
```

I understand that I can use the throttle operator to emit values only after a given time

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .throttle(val => Rx.Observable.interval(5000)
  .subscribe(m => console.log('ping'))
```

But when I try something like

```
  Rx.Observable.fromPromise(mongo.AllWishes)
    .throttle(val => Rx.Observable.interval(5000))
    .flatMap(array => Rx.Observable.from(array))
    .pluck('url')
    .filter(s => s !== undefined)
    .subscribe(m => console.log(m))
```

I get an error

```
rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.js:76
                    root_1.root.setTimeout(function () { throw err; });
                                                         ^    
TypeError: this.durationSelector is not a function
```

What am I missing ? 
Thank your for your help

Comment: What's `mongo.AllWishes`?

Comment: @martin mongo.AllWhishes is a promise that resolve to an array [ { "url" : "http://something.com/hello" }, { "url": "http://something.com/world" } ]

Comment: @Yoshi yes it was a typo I edited my question

Comment: A promise will only emit once. What are you trying to do every 5 seconds? Do you want to take the array and emit each item sequentially every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your expectations. It looks like you are getting an array from a promise and are then wanting to emit each value sequentially with 5 seconds in-between each item.

If so, I think that this should do what you want. As far as your error it is hard to tell without being able to run your code. I'm assuming it has something to do with your promise since I can replace `mongo.AllWishes` with my own promise and it doesn't error.

```js
const data = [
  { url: 'https://something.com/1' },
  { url: 'https://something.com/2' },
  { url: 'https://something.com/3' },
  { url: 'https://something.com/4' },
  { url: 'https://something.com/5' }
];
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
 setTimeout(() => { resolve(data); }, 1000);
});


Rx.Observable.fromPromise(myPromise)
 .flatMap(x => {
   return Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
    .takeWhile(i => i < x.length)
    .map(i => x[i]);
 })
 .pluck('url')
  .subscribe((url) => { console.log(url); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.10/Rx.min.js"></script>
```